# Objective-c TableView Refresh With dispatch_sync error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

Hello I have working simple tableview json parsing codes. But i want to do reload tableview in background everytime i added dispatch_sync codes but don't working my codes under.

```
NSArray * jsonArray;
NSMutableArray * array1;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bla.com/test2.json"];

    NSURLRequest * urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSError * error;

    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlReq returningResponse:nil error:&error];

    NSDictionary * jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);

    jsonArray = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"worldpopulation"];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray);

    array1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

- (void)main
{

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return jsonArray.count;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellid=@"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell=(CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];;


    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[CustomTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];

    }



    for ( NSDictionary * dict in jsonArray) {

        NSString * country = [dict objectForKey:@"country"];

        [array1 addObject:country];

    }

    cell.nameLabel.text= [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;
}
```

Main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I added only needed codes . I need to fix it . 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is specifically going wrong when you do this?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam don't reload table when i changed remote json while waiting.

Comment: You don't actually call `reloadData` anywhere (you have a function called `main` that does this, but you don't call that anywhere in  the code shown).  Also, executing synchronous network requests on the main thread is a terrible idea  - you will block the whole App UI

Comment: @Paulw11 which codes i need ? my codes there and how can i do this ? thanks

Comment: show us your code when calling your `main` function

Comment: @setonugroho added dude

Comment: it seems that you are misunderstood about your main function. You declare `(void)main` function in your code to reload table, but you don't call it from anywhere.

Comment: add `[self main];` below `array1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, performing synchronous network operations on the main thread is a bad idea - it will make your app UI 'freeze' until the operation completes, which in the case of a slow (or no) network could be a long time.

Secondly, you should move the loading code into its own function that you call from `viewDidLoad` - this way you can easily call it again if you want to reload the data.

Thirdly, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is iterating your entire `jsonArray` for each cell to no purpose.

Finally, `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS 9 so you should migrate to `NSURLSession` if you are targeting iOS7 and later (if you want to run on iOS prior to iOS 7 then you will need to keep using NSURLConnection)

I would suggest the following:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *jsonArray;

@end

@implementation MyViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.jsonArray=[NSArray new];
    [self loadJSON];
}

-(void)loadJSON {

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bla.com/test2.json"];
    NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];

   [session dataTaskWithRequest:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong:%@",error);
        } else {
            NSError *jsonError;
            NSDictionary * jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonEerror];
            if (jsonError != nil) {
                NSLog(@"JSON isn't right:%@",jsonError);
            } else {
                self.jsonArray = jsonDict[@"worldpopulation"];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    [self.tableview reloadData];
                }); 
            }
    }];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.jsonArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellid=@"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell=(CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid forIndexPath:indexPath];;

    NSDictionary *entryDict=self.jsonArray[indexPath.row];
    NSString *countryName=entryDict[@"country"];

    cell.nameLabel.text= countryName;
    return cell;
}
```